# Mongodb : Why convert string date to ISOdate if comparison operators work?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following kind of document:

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("538d64a11ca6e50941fda4d9"), "_id" : "538d518e20b8fd642e0000e8", 
  "posts" : "some stuff", "date" : "2014-06-02"
}
```

Using comparison operators for a string date (Not the Mongodb ISODate) works:

```
> collection.find({"date": {"$gte": "2014-06-02"}})
```

So why shall we (bother to) convert string dates to an ISODate then?

Comment: Stringly typed systems are never easy to maintain later on in life.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably the biggest advantage of using the MongoDB BSON Date type instead of a string is that you can only use the `aggregate` [Date operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#date-operators) with BSON Date values.

But if you don't need to do any aggregation of your data, using a sortable string format to represent dates is fine and often cleaner as you don't need to deal with time zone related display problems.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer! I don't need to use aggregate but that's a very sound reason for converting to Date since I may use it in the future!