# Should i use a day string field instead of date range?

Tags: mongodb

We rely a lot on date range filter for daily app usage

ex:

```
{
   date: {
     $gte: ISODate("2018-10-26"),
     $lte: ISODate("2018-10-27"),
   }
 }
```

But a lot of those query appears in the "slow query" list.
So i was thinking to add a string "day" field on every document

ex:

```
{
    day: "2018-10-26"
}
```

But i can't find any performance difference between the two queries using 
`.explain()`

I understand that `totalDocsExamined` and `totalKeysExamined` are the same for both query, but i can't find a way to compare the average "scanning" complexity (which i think will show the second method superiority).

Is it worth it ?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25686847/mongodb-why-convert-string-date-to-isodate-if-comparison-operators-work

Comment: Do you have an index on `date`…?

Answer (score 0):

Insted of that you can use _id field for your date range query. Since id in MongoDB is based on timestamp. Simple js query for date range -

```
function objectIdWithTimestamp(timestamp) {
    // Convert string date to Date object (otherwise assume timestamp is a date)
    if (typeof(timestamp) == 'string') {
        timestamp = new Date(timestamp);
    }

    // Convert date object to hex seconds since Unix epoch
    var hexSeconds = Math.floor(timestamp/1000).toString(16);

    // Create an ObjectId with that hex timestamp
    var constructedObjectId = ObjectId(hexSeconds + "0000000000000000");

    return constructedObjectId
};

var start = new Date(2018, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
var startId = objectIdWithTimestamp(start.getTime());

db.user.find({"_id": { "$gte": startId }})
```

Since _id is indexed it should be faster! you can use this same logic with any driver as well. I do it on go!